# SQL sub queries error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select(select SUM(HOME_SCORE) total from MATCH )
        +
(select SUM(AWAY_SCORE) total from MATCH) 
as "GOALS SCORED"
From dual ;
```

this is meant to return the sum of HOME_SCORE and AWAY_SCORE I get the following error

> Error starting at line : 242 in command -
>   select(select SUM(HOME_SCORE) total from MATCH )
>   Error report -
>   Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line : 243 in command -
>   +
>   Error report -
>   Unknown Command
>
> Query Run In:Query Result

Comment: At least in ANSI SQL `MATCH` is a reserved word, delimit as `"MATCH"`.

Comment: `select SUM(HOME_SCORE) + SUM(AWAY_SCORE) total from "MATCH"`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on 11g XE. Oracle errors start with a code (e.g. `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected)` and you are getting none: I'm pretty sure the error comes from your application.

Comment: Additionally, do you need so many subqueries? I have the impression your code equals `SELECT SUM(HOME_SCORE)+SUM(AWAY_SCORE) AS "GOALS SCORED" FROM MATCH` :-?

Comment: Like Alvaro, I can't reproduce the problem. On my copy of 11.2 XE I get an error message "table or view does not exist" (obviously, since I don't have a table MATCH on my system); nothing about an unknown command.

Comment: Alvaro Gonzalez it was indeed a problem with the application. I shut down and restarted oracle and no problems  Thanks : )

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your lacking in parenthesis if you want that way please rewrite your script to this `select((select SUM(HOME_SCORE) total from MATCH )
        +
(select SUM(AWAY_SCORE) total from MATCH)) 
as "GOALS SCORED"
From dual ;`

or to simplify this you can try this `select(select SUM(HOME_SCORE) + SUM(AWAY_SCORE) total from MATCH )
as "GOALS SCORED"
From dual ;`